# trigger event for webhooks in braintree

Tags: node.js, webhooks, braintree

i am trying to implement braintree in my app. i tries to use webhooks to get notification. as docs of webhooks says i webhooks send http post request to destination url. inside my destination url i wrote the following code.

```
router.post('/webhooks',function(req,res){
    gateway.webhookNotification.parse(
    req.body.bt_signature,
    req.body.bt_payload,
    function(err,webhookNotification){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.send("[Webhook Received " + webhookNotification.timestamp + "] | Kind: " + webhookNotification.kind + " | Subscription: " + webhookNotification.subscription.id)
    })
})
```

my notification is on for all the provided list. but when i subscribe i dont get any notification or **i don't know how to get notification**. but when i change my route option to GET request and write following code

```
router.get('/webhooks',function(req,res){
    sampleNotification = gateway.webhookTesting.sampleNotification(
    braintree.WebhookNotification.Kind.SubscriptionWentPastDue,
    "myId"
    );
    gateway.webhookNotification.parse(
    sampleNotification.bt_signature,
    sampleNotification.bt_payload,
    function(err,webhookNotification){
        if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.send("[Webhook Received " + webhookNotification.timestamp + "]   |   Kind: " + webhookNotification.kind + " | Subscription: " +    webhookNotification.subscription.id)
    })
 })
```

i get notification details. now my concern is should i have to declare  ***braintree.WebhookNotification.Kind*** or it is self declared when event occur? how to get notification when subscribed(or any events). in POST method?

Comment: What kind of webhook are you looking for? Is it for submerchant approval or disbursement?

Comment: i am looking for disbursement @NnN

Comment: There are 2 type of disbursement webhooks, one is for _transaction disbursed_ another is for _disbursement_. If you are looking for _transaction disbursed_ then you will get response at the end of each day to your **web method** or if you are looking for _Disbursement_ you will get response only after couple of days. I hope you have created webhook URL in your sandbox...

Comment: yes i have created webhook url (public url on web). now how notification is gained should i have to check sandbox dashbord for notification ? @NnN

Comment: No, as per the doc, your POST method should have arguments, BrainTree will send response to that argument during function call. You can check the response values either by saving them in to database or creating log files.

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

This seems pretty specific to your integration with webhooks, I'd recommend reaching out to Braintree support for help, their email address is: support@braintreepayments.com.